# Odoo add action to workflow mrp.production gets parseError

Tags: workflow, odoo-8, parse-error

Hello I want to add an action to the Manufacturing Orders (**mrp.production**), so after the "new" there is a step "measuring", which then comes between "new" and "ready to produce". I tried following code

*mrp_new_workflows.xml:*

```
<openerp>
<data>

<record id="prod_act_nametingen" model="workflow.activity">               
        <field name="name">nametingen</field>                        
        <field name="wkf_id" ref="mrp.production"/>   
        <field name="kind">function</field> 
        <field name="action">action_nametingen()</field> 
</record>
<record id="prod_trans_done_nametingen" model="workflow.transition">       
        <field name="act_from" ref="mrp.production.prod_act_done"/>               
        <field name="act_to" ref="prod_act_nametingen"/>
         <field name="signal">confirm_nametingen</field>                                                             
</record> 
</data>
</openerp>
```

But then I get following error: **ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: mrp.production"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

instead of "**mrp.production.prod_act_done**" in **ref** give "**mrp.prod_act_done**"

Change this line -> `<field name="act_from" ref="mrp.production.prod_act_done"/>`

to-> `<field name="act_from" ref="mrp.prod_act_done"/>`

When specifying **reference** you have to refer the **folder name**, not the object

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, does this count for the ref to in line <field name="wkf_id" ref="mrp.production"/> ??? because here is were I get an error on the mrp.production